# Database structure for storing timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website, in that i start time after user login, and when i stop the timer I save this time in database, And i have two tables

```
login 
----------------------
id | username | password 

table 
---------------------------------------------
user_id(referenced by id) | t_id | date | time
```

So, With this database structure i got multiple entry in database when i logout, 
So plz tell me about proper database structure for storing the time datewise and for one date only one entry allowed.

If there are any suggesion for re-design database structure then plz suggest me.

i want to merge the time in database, when i logout the multiple time in single day...

Comment: More information is needed.

Comment: do you want to store time of login and logout?

Comment: yes, i can already store the time in table(time). but dont want multiple entries for single date..

Comment: You want to store all of the times that you logged out in one day, or just the recent one? If the former, to normalize your database you should be adding a row for each logout and then you can write your select queries in such a manner that they extract the information they want so that your database will be in normal form.

Comment: Why don't you want multiple entries for a single day? What if someone logs in multiple times on a single day? How will you handle that?

Comment: Also why are you storing date and time separately? Isn't it easier to only store a timestamp (which has both the date and the time)?

Comment: actually i want user to login for 9 hours per day, so i want to merge the time in per single day.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Do you want it to update with the most recent logout time that day?

Comment: That is vital information about your problem. Please add it to your question or no one is going to understand what you want.

Comment: no, i am talking about combine with old time, so i just want user to login for 9 hours only, i dont want other details like how many time they login or logout.

Comment: There is no `combine` keyword in SQL. What you want can only be achieved by updating. Also this is not a question of database design. You have to write code that checks if a record exists already. If yes: update; if no: insert. Again, this has nothing to do with database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table 
---------------------------------------------
user_id(referenced by id) | login_date (datetime field) | logout_date (datetime field)
```

Answer (score 0):

If So then store Login time and logout time in the table .Find the difference of all log outs and logins in the current date and finally sum up all the differences if it is greater than or equal to 9 disable login function